# chrome.tabs.create not working on Chrome startup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have a simple Chrome extension, with just this little code inside background.js file:

```
chrome.tabs.create({}, function (tab) {
    console.log(tab.id);
});
```

When I install it through developer mode, it creates a new tab and writes its id to console.

But when I exit Chrome and start it again, nothing happens on Chrome startup.. I thought background scripts are loaded on each browser startup?

What is wrong with this and is there any other way to do this on browser startup?

Comment: Chrome disables manually installed extensions on every start unless you patch the dll.

Comment: Can you point me into that direction?

Comment: [How to hack chrome.dll to get rid of the "disable developer mode extensions" pop up](//stackoverflow.com/a/30361260)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. One thing comes to my mind now, I put a console.log before chrome.tabs.create call inside background.js, and it is executed properly on Chrome startup. So it seems like it's not blocking whole extension, just call to the Chrome Extension API (like chrome.tabs.create).

Comment: @wOxxOm Forget my previous comment, I wasn't right about it, console.log was left from some previous instance.

I followed the instructions, and hacked chrome.dll successfully, but still my background.js  code doesn't run on Chrome startup... Any other idea for it?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue though my code runs, it's just that chrome.tabs.create() doesn't work on startup. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest and add background property:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

Chrome will run this script "background.js" on browser startup every time(till your extension enabled).
So just add you code to background.js script.

```
 //background.js content
    chrome.tabs.create({}, function (tab) {
        console.log(tab.id);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a lot of experience with Chrome Extensions and I know how background works. But it doesn't work in the situation I wrote in my question.